# override a css table

Tags: css, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

i have a problem  with  overriding a css table  class

im  using  !important but it's not working

a part of my css file

```
         table tr td
         {background: #F0EFE2;
          background: #FFF;
           color: #47433F;

           border-top: 1px solid #FFF;}
```

when  i  use   the class    "field-validation-error"   not  working  even  if  it have a red color

```
       <td>
    <span class="field-validation-error" data-valmsg-for="nom_candidat"
     data-valmsg-replace="true">Le champ Nom est requis.</span>  </td>
```

Comment: you forgot about dot, it should be `.table tr td`

Comment: @SergeyBoiko - `table` is HTML element not a class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems to work.

See my test here: [http://jsbin.com/wadud/1/edit](http://jsbin.com/wadud/1/edit?html,css,output).